# Is it possible to access another DataFrame while iterating through a DataFrame?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When iterating through a Dataframe using `.foreach` in Spark Scala is it possible to access another DataFrame, or load a DataFrame from SparkSQL, to make comparisons? For example, DF1 has available days and if a day is marked as not available on DF1 but appears on DF2 I would like to ignore that row of DF1. I have the logic working when I do a `.collect` on DF1 and iterate, but DF1 will be a large dataset and I do not want to be pulling all of that data back on to the driver.

```
DF1 Schema
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- monday: boolean (nullable = false)
 |-- tuesday: boolean (nullable = false)
 |-- wednesday: boolean (nullable = false)
 |-- thursday: boolean (nullable = false)
 |-- friday: boolean (nullable = false)
 |-- saturday: boolean (nullable = false)
 |-- sunday: boolean (nullable = false)

 DF2 Schema
 |-- start: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- end: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- dayStart: string (nullable = false)
 |-- dayEnd: string (nullable = false)
```

Comment: Use `join` when your query involves relations between two dataframes. Avoid iterating rows.

Comment: @mck based on the schemas I mentioned above how would you suggest joining? or should I add columns to the one of the DataFrames so that I can perform a join?

Comment: @saragallagher you can do some transformation to create a column that you can use for comparison while doing join and that won't be tough. you could do that easily. Also try to provide some sample data so someone can help you.